# Trouble launching Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, macos

This is silly, but I am running out of ideas.

I downloaded the latest eclipse (EE) 64 bit package for my mac, untarred it and upon launching it, got an error message. Reopening it, of course did not work.

[image]

I tried:

- Rebooting
- Downloading package from multiple mirrors
- Downloading non-EE version fails with same error
- Downloading `Indigo` version - starts up and runs fine.

I have already installed:

- Standard `Juno` installed (non EE). It can run without any issues. Could there be a conflict with anything here?
- New non-EE version Juno install fails with the same error as EE version

I am not sure what else to try or how this behavior can be explained. Any ideas?

I am running on 10.8.2 OSX (Mountain Lion) with security settings enabled to

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the [Unarchiver](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12). As part of untarring, it corrupted something.

Once tarball was untarred manually, everything worked like a charm. No magic.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble in the same situation.
After the latest update eclipse.ini file was lost in Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS folder.
I recovered it and  restarted eclipse(eclipse -clean). Successfully it started working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? When i downloaded eclipse,it comes as a archive, in which i execute the Eclipse.app. I see no way to look inside that. Additionally (and this may be a clue), when i try to launch eclipse from command line, i get `➜  eclipse  ./eclipse -clean
[1]    14749 segmentation fault  ./eclipse -clean`

Comment: Set your mouse-cursor on the /Application/Eclipse.app. Then right-click, show contents of package. You can open the contents of Eclipse.app.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, took forever to figure it out because I just updated eclipse.ini then it was gone again after an update.

A recent bug about Eclipse Update removing the eclipse.ini in Mac OS X (Sept 29, 2012)
"Bug 390756 - Juno SR1 update is removing the eclipse.ini file"
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390756#c40

See comment: David Williams 2012-10-10 16:15:52 EDT:

> Starting fresh from SR0 or SR1 works fine, but starting with the already
>   broken version (even with eclipse.ini restored) does indeed delete the
>   eclipse.ini.